# Angularjs: going through json checking out if linked files exist

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I would like to go through my json file where I have objects with a link attribute

id:1
name: name
link: http://www.domain.com/file.doc.pdf.xls
type: a
.
.
.

My html shows the name with a href=link....
What is the best way to embed the  tag only if the link exists or not?
Or should I write a script first that changes the json and puts all the links:"" to zero?

Could you give me some examples on how I should do this in Angular?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple links and if You are using ng-repeat then use angular filter ,

i Hope this will help you.

<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{link:'!'}">
</li>